# .NET Azure Function - How do I return a JSON object from a stream?

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-functions

I need to stream JSON out of an Azure function without serializing the object because serializiation overhead is too costly.
The code boils down to something like this:

```
[FunctionName("AzureFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> 
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/function")], HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);

    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Property");
    jsonWriter.WriteValue("Value");
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/json");
}
```

However this JSON is being converted to a string before hitting the wire at some point. I've been able to pass a stream from another HTTP call directly through to a FileStreamResult object and that does not get converted to a string so I'm sure this is possible.

Comment: *"However this JSON is being converted to a string before hitting the wire at some point."* How do you know that?

Comment: The client calling this received a string, upon further inspection it was because the object was not fully enclosed with the closing tag because it hadn't been flushed.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, the Stream needs to be flushed before returning. The correct code looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("AzureFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> 
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/function")], HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);

    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Property");
    jsonWriter.WriteValue("Value");
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

    jsonWriter.Flush(); // Flush the json before returning.
    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/json");
}
```